# nvidia-settings doesn't detect GPU when run over X11 forwarding

Tags: linux, nvidia, x11-forwarding

I try to run nvidia-settings command in Ubuntu machine remotely from a Windows machine using X11 forwarding. The GUI came up, but it didn't detect any card that resided on the machine. It said:

```
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
```

any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well, I just need to set the display to 0.0 in the ssh session by executing:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```